# Enhanced Grid Sorting Not working properly

Tags: datagrid, dojo

I am using Enhanced grid and I found recently that on sorting any column (by clicking on the column name of the header), the sorting is breaking and not working on the complete results if the results of that column has special characters like `"|,*/\-&` etc. ... Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<body>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
        <div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" 
            jsId="appsStoreForGrid" data="storeData" typeMap="_typeMap">
        </div>

        <div id="grid" data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid" 
            data-dojo-props="store:appsStoreForGrid, structure:'layoutApps',
            errorMessage:'No Data Found', 
            plugins: { 
                filter: { closeFilterbarButton: true, ruleCount: 5 }, 
                pagination: { pageSizes: ['5', '25', '50', '100'], 
                    description: true, sizeSwitch: true, pageStepper: true, 
                    gotoButton: true, maxPageStep: 8, position: 'top'}}">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please post what you have written so far.

Comment: Code:-

<body>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
        <div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" jsId="appsStoreForGrid" data="storeData" typeMap="_typeMap"></div>       
 
   <div id="grid" data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid" data-dojo-props="store:appsStoreForGrid, structure:'layoutApps', errorMessage:'No Data Found' , plugins: { filter: { closeFilterbarButton: true, ruleCount: 5 }, pagination: {pageSizes: ['5', '25', '50', '100'], description: true,sizeSwitch: true,pageStepper: true, gotoButton: true, maxPageStep: 8, position: 'top'} }"></div>  
    </div>

</body>

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error. But on sorting based on one of the column which has special characters and alphanumeric values, its sorting weird way. Its working fine for initial 15-20 rows, but again getting broken and then working back till the rest of the rows.

Comment: It's very hard to tell what "sorting in a weird way means" without seeing the actual results. Please show us.

Comment: I have uploaded in goggle.. Link below..

https://plus.google.com/photos/102166645920992518925/albums/5927568916202214337?banner=pwa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to SPACES in front of content which was causing bad sorting. Those spaces were not visible in the browser, but when viewing the page source I came to know about it. Finally TRIM the spaces in Db only and the issue is resolved now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, your sort is actually working correctly. Rows in your grid are sorted based on string ordering, which depends on the values of the strings, given by [ASCII codes](http://www.asciitable.com/). So let's take a look at part of your first image:

```
TEST Email to Check references
Test 1 |ID:1141|
```

The `|` in this case has very little to do with the ordering. When we translate these strings to their ASCII codes (in decimal), we get this (truncated to the first 10 characters):

```
T   E   S   T       E   m   a   i   l
84  69  83  84  32  69  109 97  105 108 
    |                                 <-- 69 < 101, so this is correct
84  101 115 116 32  49  32  124 73  68
T   e   s   t       1       |   I   D
```

So you can see how the sorting function organizes these strings based on value. Similarly, in picture #2:

```
*** UPDATE-COMPLETED ***
**UPDATE-CMPLETE**
9-20-13-Loads and Mtys
```

For this we only need to look at the first few characters: `***`, `**U`, and `9-20`, which have the values of `42 42 42`, `42 42 85`, and `57 45 50`, respectively; so once again they are in order.

If you want to ignore special characters, your best bet is to not allow them in your datagrid in general, so you'll need to parse them out.

Comment: Sorry but i don't agree with you. 
If you see the 3rd Image then, you will find that "A P P O I N T M E N T .." is coming after "9/20/2013 ..". But "APPOINTMENT" row should have come in the initial start along with the other rows having "A" in beginning and not after the "9/20/2013" marks. That's where it's distorted.
Please Let me know if I was able to make it clear.

Comment: The sorting is still technically correct - `'A'` = `65` > `57` = `'9'`.

Comment: I guess you didn't get my point. Let me try again.
After Sorting the Subject Column, the initial rows are fine. They starts with Apple,, then Boy, then Columbus etc.... THEN Comes the row having TEST EMAIL.. Its fine till now... THEN COMES YOUR *** .. then 9-20-13.... THEN AGAIN COMES ROW HAVING "APPOINTEMENT"...then row having "BASEBALL"... then "CHALLENGE"..etc.. 
Don't you think that "APPOINTMENT" row should have come after "APPlE". .... AND BASEBALL should have come after BOY... but its broken inbetween by the numbers & special characters.

HOPE I AM CLEAR THIS TIME.. Sorry if not.

Comment: I'm still unsure where you see a problem. Sorting is case-sensitive, and from your above comment, your examples change wildly from "Apple" to "APPIE". `'A' = 65 != 97 = 'a'`.

Please keep your composure. I understand you are frustrated, but we do our best here to help given the information we have.

Comment: Sorry, but you really not getting the issue.Or I am not able to make you clear. I have uploaded a new pdf. Link below..
http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/26544418

If you see the first rows are sorted fine, then once the *** 9/20/2013 comes, it gets bad. and then again gets sorted fine.. Scroll the pdf and zoom it and tell me if thats looks sorted to you based on Subject Column.